# Use the Mozilla Backpack Connect API with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, openbadge

I would like to issue a badge with the *Mozilla Backpack Connect API* ([check this !](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-backpack/blob/master/docs/apis/backpack_connect.md)). To do so, I have followed [this document](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-backpack/wiki/Using-the-Backpack-Connect-API) but I still cannot issue a badge !

*I have the exact same problem when I just try to get a new access token using the refresh token. So I've posted the "get new access token" code here because it's a bit easier to understand than the issuing one.*

I would like to do this in *PHP* with *cURL*, not in *Javascript*.

Here is my code :

```
$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token' => $refreshToken
);
$url = $apiRoot .'/token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w+'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);

curl_close($ch);
```

Here I just trying to get a new access token, as mentioned in [the same document](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-backpack/wiki/Using-the-Backpack-Connect-API), but unfortunately, I always get this response :

> Bad Request: Bad Request
>   at next (/var/www/openbadges/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:125:13)
>   at /var/www/openbadges/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:54:23
>   at IncomingMessage. (/var/www/openbadges/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:74:60)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
>   at _stream_readable.js:938:16
>   at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

If I look deeper, I have verbosed the request and it gives me this :

> > POST /api/token HTTP/1.1
>   Host: backpack.openbadges.org
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Content-Length: 81
>
> * upload completely sent off: 81 out of 81 bytes
>   * additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
>   * HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
>   < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   < Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
>   < Content-Type: text/plain
>   < Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 12:36:03 GMT
>   < Set-Cookie: AWSELB=674101290634B07D75A3C1417FA6788D6E65270EC8D2D0E6014FB81FA4E878CAEA117D6E6334DB190F94A3D84909E9928F08D6B81651BDC3386AFC0A84F3A39F4B51E09B31;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=3600
>   < x-frame-options: DENY
>   < X-Powered-By: Express
>   < Content-Length: 478
>   < Connection: keep-alive
>   <
>   * Connection #0 to host backpack.openbadges.org left intact
>   * Closing connection #0

So, basically, it responses me an error 400 "Bad Request" with no more information...

For information, if I try to do it with *Javascript*, it works. If I do this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://backpack.openbadges.org/api/token',
    data: {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: theRefreshToken
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, req) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log($(this));
    }
});
```

This returns me a success, but when I use the *PHP cURL* it doesn't work ! So why ?

And my badge is valid (it passes [the validation](http://validator.openbadges.org/) without problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched for hours ! The solution is really simple but not so obvious...

On this line : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));` you have to use `json_encode()` instead of `http_build_query()` !

So doing like this : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));` and it works ! Yay !

Comment: well, yeah... you tell the service you're sending json, then send over form-encoded data...

Comment: Yeah okay, maybe it's obvious for you.. But I've really found nothing on the subject concerning sending badges with php. So I hope this post will help someone.

Comment: that's because you searched for the wrong thing. PHP has no idea what a "badge" is, and couldn't care less. you were doing an http request, to a service that expects data in format X, and you were sending format Y.